# Create popup "window" above a UIView

Tags: uiview, ios6

I would like to create a small popup window that appears in front of an existing `UIView`. This popup window needs to take text input and have a button on it. This popup window should appear when a `UIButton` is pressed.

I'm using a storyboard and am wondering what is the best approach to complete this? Should I just be using another `UIView`? If so, how do I go about creating the new view on top of the existing `UIView`?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be as simple as adding a new UIView with all the various controls / labels you want in it and put that new view on top of your view controller's main view (this might be considered as a subview).

Then set the new view to an outlet in your view controller and hide it (via the attributes inspector).

[image: Set The Hidden Attribute]

When the button is touched, you can programatically set the "popup window" view's "`.hidden`" property to "`NO`".